# After 15.10 upgrade, lost the skype external (logitech camera) mic option

Tags: skype, microphone, 15.10

I've upgraded to ubuntu 15.10 and I lost the mic in my skype.
The mic was working correctly before the upgrade.

The mic is working when testing it in the Setting->Sound->input area. It is marked as Microphone, QuickCam Communicate MP/s5500

When looking into the Skype mic settings, there is only one option in the drop down menu: Options->Sound Devices->Michrophone = PulseAudio server (local)

There is no Camera option as there was before.

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The problem was due to the default profile of the sound card.
After the upgrade I initially had sound but no mic on Skype as described in this question. But later I lost all sound on the computer and opened another question on it.

[My other question on askubuntu regarding the sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692844/no-sound-after-14-10-15-04-15-10-upgrade/693760#693760)

I found that the card default is set to Digital and not Analog each time I switch to another sound card (my TV is connected to the computer). So I need to set it manually each time I come back to the Computer's sound card using the

> Pulseaudio Volume Control

The same worked for the Skype mic. You can access it directly from Skype settings if you have the Pulseaudio Volume Control installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete the pulseaudio config and profile files so that pulseaudio is forced to generate new ones:

```
rm -r ~/.pulse/
```

restart pulseaudio or your computer afterwards

Comment: Thanks, the pulseaudio is recognizing the camera's mic. I can see the input camera volume running  while checking the pulseaudio volume settings. Skype does not have the option to change to the camera mic

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this last night with my MX Revolution mouse and keyboard -- may work for you too.  Here's what I found on a french site:

Edit /lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules

Change this line:

```
KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[3bc]", \
  RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p"
```

to be this (Change hiddev* to hidraw*):

```
    KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[3bc]", \
      RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p"
```

Comment: I do not see any difference between the two lines of code...

Comment: Oops -- fixed it now :)