# No sound after 14.10 -> 15.04 -> 15.10 upgrade

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 15.10

I've upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04 and then directly to 15.10.

I have a TV connected to the computer via HDMI cable.
The sound was working ok after the upgrade but after using the TV and coming back to the computer, I do not have the sound anymore.

Tried restarting the computer but no sound. 
When getting the logging screen, I do hear the sound though.

Looking into the settings->sound I only have the digital option and no analog option in the drop down menu.

Things I've tried:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Killed the pulseaudio process and it restarted again automatically. Still no sound.

Reinstalled Alsa and Pulseaudio

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
$ sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
$ sudo alsa force-reload
```

Restarted but no success. 
I also lost the volume icon in the top bar and the settings-sound looks a bit different now.

[image]

The device option did change though and now shows

```
HDMI / DisplayPort - built-in Audio
```

instead of just `built-in Audio`

Tried uninstalling Alsa and Pulse and reinstalling with the HDMI and TV not connected to the computer but got the same results.

Deleting the .config->pulse folder + logout, login didn't help

Here is the result of a `$ aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: VT1708S Digital [VT1708S Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

In the settings->sound profile, I only have

> Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output

This is a screen shoot of the Alsamixer

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. I found out that the card profile is changing automatically to Digital each time I choose to use a different card (the one from the TV) and come back to the one of the computer.
So, it come back to

> Digital Stereo (HDMI) output

and I need to change it manually each time to

> Analog Stereo Output (unplugged)

It is a bit strange to me because the Analog Stereo is marked as "unplugged" but it is working and I'm getting the sound back.

[image]

Tried to change the default profile of the card but no success so far. I will open another question about it

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems and all the forums I could find were talking about PulseAudio and AlsaMixer. None of those solutions worked for me.

I finally found my solution in updating my Graphic Cards driver from which the HDMI cable was connected using these following steps: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

You might not have the same graphic cards or any but you might give it a try to update your driver.

Answer (score -1):

Try in console, as normal user:

pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo

and reiniciate, after that analog stereo will be configurated