# Headphone or Earphone stopped working after upgrade to 15.10

Tags: 15.10

I upgraded my ubuntu from 14.04 to 15.10 and now any of headphone or earphone have stopped working. When I donot connect any external device sound comes as usual using inetrnal speakers. Please let me know what shoud I do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the setting/configuration of pulseaudio? Maybe something went wrong during the update to 15.10.

To check your configuration you have to install pavucontrol (if you haven't installed it before):

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Comment: I looked into the settings but I could not find anything wrong or may be I am not aware of the right settings.

Comment: Go to pavucontrol->output devices (or something like that) and make sure that the computer recognize your head/earphones.

Comment: This post should fix your problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/692844/no-sound-after-14-10-15-04-15-10-upgrade?rq=1 (scroll down to see the (possible) answer for your problem.